# How to replace grep -oP in FreeBSD

Tags: bash, grep

i'm porting this [script](https://github.com/sayan01/scripts/blob/master/yt) to FreeBSD, but it fails because it needs grep -oP.

This is what the variable response is:

```
response=$(curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$query" |\
      sed 's|\\.||g')"
```

This is the apparently offending line:

```
grep -oP "$1" <<< "$response" | awk -F\" -v p="$2" '{ print $1 "\t" p " " $NF}'
```

apparently $1 is this

```
vgrep='"videoRenderer":{"videoId":"\K.{11}".+?"text":".+?[^\\](?=")'
pgrep='"playlistRenderer":{"playlistId":"\K.{34}?","title":{"simpleText":".+?[^\"](?=")'
```

or  could be this:

```
 response="$(curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$query" |\
      sed 's|\\.||g')"
```

What i want to do is make the script usable without GNU grep.
This is what i attemtp to do:

1. Replace grep -oP for grep -oE -> Result=Failed
2. Replace grep -oP for perl -nle'$1' -> Result=Failed
3. Replace grep -oP for awk ":" '$1' -> Result=Failed

Comment: I think the answer will depend heavily on what format `$1` is supposed to support.

Comment: Hi   @TedLyngmo i added the contents of the $response variable.

Comment: That's fine, but `$1` is more interesting. Anyway, I gave an answer that may help.

Comment: Install pcregrep and use that?

Comment: So that we know what the value of `$1` is, just add `echo "$1"` to your script just before your `grep` line, and then add that output to your question.

Comment: @ShaneBishop already updated with that info. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`grep -oP "$1"` could (probably) be converted to `perl` like this:

```
perl -ne 'print $& . "\n" if /'"$1"/
```

- `print $&` prints the matching string (`$1`)
- if the line matches `$1`

Disclaimer: I have no way of testing if it does the job properly since I don't know what `$1` may be

Comment: Thanks It started working, only displays one result but is a step in the  good direction.

Comment: Apparently $1 is (for grep) "a reference to the first argument passed to that script or function". I haven't found $1 value on the script.

Comment: @E.Argañaraz  `$1` is the first argument to the function in the script or to the script itself as you say. The question is what it is :-) Anyway, if `grep -P` and `perl` uses the same PCRE (the regex engine inside perl) my replacement should do the same thing - in the vast majority of cases. There could be tiny differences but to explore those, I'd need to see what `$1` is.

Answer (score 1):

The full relevant part of the code is:

```
response="$(curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$query" |\
  sed 's|\\.||g')"
# regex expression to match video and playlist entries from yt result page
vgrep='"videoRenderer":{"videoId":"\K.{11}".+?"text":".+?[^\\](?=")'
pgrep='"playlistRenderer":{"playlistId":"\K.{34}?","title":{"simpleText":".+?[^\"](?=")'
# grep the id and title
# return them in format id (type) title
getresults() {
    grep -oP "$1" <<< "$response" |\
      awk -F\" -v p="$2" '{ print $1 "\t" p " " $NF}'
}
# get the list of videos/playlists and their ids in videoids and playlistids
videoids=$(getresults "$vgrep")
playlistids=$(getresults "$pgrep" "(playlist)")
```

That `grep -oP` looks like a cheap JSON parser. Instead you can:

- Rewrite the regular expressions in `sed`. The single PERL extension is `(?=")` which can looks like it can be replaced here by just `[^"]*`.
- install `jq` and parse the response as actuall json using a json aware tool, instead of a regex hack.
- Use python or other programming language that has json parser.

Or you can just install `pcregrep` in FreeBSD.

I see no value in hacky `grep -oP` parsing here, I would just use `jq`.

Side note: there is no need for `\` in `|\`. The `|` ignores newlines anyway.